# Find & Replace blank cells in a dynamic range after transfering data into it VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Okay I know there are multiple questions similar to this, but at least from what I've found, my problem is different so please bear with me.
  I am building a user form that allows users to input data into a tracking sheet, but there are certain scenarios where only part of the data will get submitted at a time,leaving "holes" in the tracking sheet. My goal is to fill these "holes" with a period so that way relevant data will stay together in the same row instead of getting bumped up into those holes.

```
Sheets("Tracker").Activate
Worksheets("Tracker").Columns("A:J").Replace What:="", Replacement:=".", _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False
```

I realize I am essentially telling excel to fill columns A through J with  a period, so my question is, is there an easier way to do this, or a way to specify that I only need the most recent row to contain the periods?

Update: 
This is the code I am using to find the next available row in the tracker for new data to go. Thus when portions of the previous row are missing, the macro fills those unused cells with the next rows data.

```
Set ws = Sheets("Tracker") Sheets("Tracker").Select 
ws.Range("E" & LastRow).Value = job_txtb.Text    
'Finds the last blank row
LastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 
'Adds the Job name Code into Col E & Last Blank Row
```

Comment: How does irrelevant data get bumped up into blank cells?  (Holes???) Is the data from the row below somehow being moved up?  Is there another piece of code that does that?

Comment: Will the last used Row + 1 work - or are there various blank rows within the sheet.  Also, by "transferring" do you mean transferring the data from the userform to the spreadsheet?

Comment: Last used row +1 works to an extent, but at least the way it appears to me, its going by columns, so if there is a blank cell within a row it will fill that cell with the next rows data that corresponds to that column. Also, yes transferring refers to transferring the data from the user form to the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

The following will give you the first unused row.  I don't understand why periods would be necessary.

```
With ActiveSheet
    On Error Resume Next
    lastRow = .Cells.Find("*", .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlFormulas, _
    xlWhole, xlByRows, xlNext).Row
    If Err <> 0 Then lastRow = 0
End With
firstUnusedRow = lastRow + 1

Range("A" & firstUnusedRow).Value = Textbox1.Value
Range("B" & firstUnusedRow).Value = Textbox2.Value
Range("C" & firstUnusedRow).Value = Textbox3.Value
'etc.
'etc.,,
```

Comment: Your code works well, however, I am running into an issue where after the first row in the sheet is used and I move onto Row 2, it is just replacing all of row 2 instead of moving down a row, but only when I transfer part of the data. That is why I was trying to fill blank spots with a period, so that the macro recognized that the entire previous row was full even if it was only the partial data transfer.

Comment: OK, that's beyond what I can help you with without knowing how your userform puts partial data into a row.  But the lastrow method above will give you the last used row on a sheet, regardless it is only one cell used or a thousand.  My advice is to think of each row as a single record in a database.  Give the user a listbox on the form with all the records key identifiers, so if the user wants to change or edit a particular row he can do so by simply selecting it from the listbox..

Comment: I think I got it, thanks a lot for your help! Much appreciated